Jackson module-kotlin: Unable to deserialize class if value is omitted by JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY)
The situation is:

Kotlin
REST API with request/response objects generated from OpenAPI schema (so there is a limited ability to modify them)
The generated response object looks like this:

@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
data class Foo (
    @field:JsonProperty("version")  val version: kotlin.Int,
    @field:JsonProperty("bar")  val bar: kotlin.collections.List<FooBar>,   
    ...
)


Null values and empty collections omitted from serialized response by JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY), to reduce network load.
ObjectMapper with jackson-module-kotlin

I want to write end-to end tests of the API using ktor client. It would be convenient, if I could deserialize the http response body to response class.
However, it is not possible, because jackson was unable to fill required fields (in this case empty arrays)
value failed for JSON property bar due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter bar which is a non-nullable type
Is there a way to introduce default values, either globally like 'null for non-null List is listOf()' or per-field default values in generated response objects?

Edit:
I traced the problem to openapi generator.
OAS describes default for the property
  bar:
    type: array
    items:
      $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooBar'
    default: []

That usually yields to default value also in generated class
  @field:JsonProperty("bar")
  val bar: kotlin.collections.List<FooBar>? = arrayListOf()

However this does not work (at least with openapi-generator-maven-plugin in version 7.5.0) , if the property with default value is inherited using allOf - probably issue in generator?
Maybe <openapiNormalizer>REFACTOR_ALLOF_WITH_PROPERTIES_ONLY=true</openapiNormalizer> is the issue, but the generated model was completely incorrect otherwise.

The easiest solution is to define a default value on fields that can be omitted, like follow:
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
data class Foo (
    @JsonProperty("version")  val version: Int,
    @JsonProperty("bar")  val bar: List<FooBar> = listOf(),

)

Kotlin does not do that automatically, because it does not force an arbitrary default value. For example, in your case, should it put an empty mutable or immutable list ?
With the above modification, the parsing succeeds. Let see an example:
fun main() {
    val parsed = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<Foo>(
        """
            { "version": 1 }
        """.trimIndent()
    )

    check(parsed == Foo(1))
}

